# How to gapless change from a looping video to another video and back by pressing a button in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, effect

I have a problem when I am trying to develop a small video project. In this project, I need to change from one video to another when clicking a button. The first video is looping, and then after I press the button, the video will change to the second video, and the second video will only be played once. After the second video is over, there should be a button that can be pressed. After pressing the button, we should go back to the first looping video. The key requirement is a gapless effect. The user will not notice a difference between the two videos. It is a web project, so I used JavaScript to realize it. At first, I only had one video element, so the way I changed the video from one to another was by changing the src of it. However, there will be a flash effect when changing the video. Later, I create videos that are in the same place, one after another. However, after thinking about it for a long time, the only thing I can do is use the fadeOut and fadeIn methods to create a fading effect. But it is still not good enough; is there any way to realize it?

I hope you can give me a small sample program demo with HTML, CSS, and JavaScript. Thank you~

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.